# How to fix regex not matching when a character is the first on a new line?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression I'm using to identify text that matches a markdown formatting rule, surrounded with asterisks.

I'm making sure the asterisks not only surround text, but that the asterisks are next to the text. e.g `*bold*` should work and `* not bold *` shouldn't, to avoid normal asterisks getting caught up in formatting.

This is my regex now:
`\*[^ ][^*]+.[^ ]\*`

**The problem is, this text is a positive match:**

```
*Test
ing*
```

**And this isn't:**

```
*Test
g*
```

**Both examples should match the expression.**

I'm using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3i1gdH/1) to test.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To match *any* character including new lines, you can't use `.` Try with `[\S\s]` instead

Comment: Remove the dot. Use `\*[^* ](?:[^*]*[^ *])?\*`

Comment: Do you want to match `**1**` with this regex?

Comment: The inner part should match (*1*), but I've accepted your answer since it correctly covers every appropriate case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot requires to match at least one character and the next negated character class matches any char but space obligatorily. Thus the dot fails as there is a newline before `g`.

Use

```
\*[^* ](?:[^*]*[^ *])?\*
```

Or

```
\*[^*\s](?:[^*]*[^\s*])?\*
```

These regexes match strings between asterisks containing at least one char.

**Details**

- `\*` - an asterisk
- `[^*\s]` - any one char other than asterisk and whitespace
- `(?:[^*]*[^\s*])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[^*]*` - zero or more chars other than asterisk
  - `[^\s*]` - any char other than asterisk and whitespace
- `\*` - an asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the dot as commented by @wiktor-stribiżew indeed fixes the issue, but the regex can be further simplified to `\*\S[^*]+\S\*`.

Note that this regex will also match the entire string of `**Test**`, i.e. it matches the double-asterisks. You didn't specify your intended behavior in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The following regexp matches both of your test cases:

```
\*[^ *]+.*?[^ ]\*
```

As an aside the site https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html (which I used to check your original regexp) is also an excellent place to develop and test regexp matchers and replacers.